# Clone a credit card

Tags: credit-card, emv

I wanted to ask if it's possible to clone your own credit card (clone the emv chip) and copy it onto another emv chip with an emv reader/writer.

Shouldn't this be easily possible without extracting any private keys whatsoever? Since I just want to do an identical copy of the encrypted data onto another chip. I don't want to decrypt anything.

There's already a similar post on here:

[Cloning of EMV cards](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/161169/cloning-of-emv-cards)

The difference is that I'm not asking about extracting private keys but just making a copy of the encrypted data on the chip and copying it to another blank chip.

If that shouldn't be possible for a reason could you explain why or point to a useful resource explaining that?